# Significato di "vincolo" in questa frase

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Recentemente ho letto questa frase:

> Portare il nome di un parente può rappresentare un *vincolo*.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "vincolo" nella frase precedente. L'ho cercato sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vincolo/), ma non mi è chiaro come si debba interpretare in questo contesto. Significa "una catena" in senso figurato? O si tratta piuttosto di "un legame affettivo" con il parente?

Comment: Un po' più di contesto aiuterebbe.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: La frase è tratta di un libro di esercizi di italiano. Nell'esercizio, la frase era isolata. Si trattava di vedere se la frase rappresentava un'idea espressa in alcuno di due testi e dire a quale testo si riferiva.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Grazie alla risposta di DaG, adesso mi è chiaro che la frase della domanda si riferisce a questa parte di uno dei testi: «Ma nemmeno quelli dei nonni sono facili da portare, anzi, sono ancor più pesanti. Ben più castranti sono quelli degli avi morti in guerra o per una malattia in giovane età.» Queste frasi si riferiscono al nome delle persone.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Quando ho scritto la domanda avevo il dubbio se la frase poteva anche riferirsi a quest'idea espressa nell'altro testo: «I nomi molto usati sono quelli dei nonni perché custodiscono la memoria della famiglia.»

Comment: Il mio dubbio sorge del fatto che nella mia lingua esiste anche questo vocabolo ("vincle" in catalano), ma non ha mai il significato spiegato da DaG, ma sì quello del legame che esiste tra due persone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Come hai visto “vincolo” significa in vari sensi, letterali e metaforici, “legame”, ma nel contesto di questa frase il legame è visto come qualcosa che limita, quasi ostacola, impedisce di agire liberamente (quindi non un legame affettivo o simili).

Presumibilmente qui si parla di qualcuno che è parente di un personaggio famoso e quindi già il solo nome crea delle aspettative, limita ciò che quella persona può fare e dire, mentre se si chiamasse Mario Rossi potrebbe vivere più liberamente.